# Detection of overflow in binary arithmetic

Tags: binary

I read that:

> Carry out of sign bit and carry into the sign bit 
>   will be given as two inputs to the exclusive-OR 
>   gate and the output of exclusive-OR gate is 
>   connected to overflow flip-flop.¨

What is meant by "Carry out of sign bit and carry into the sign bit?

Answer (score 0):

"carry" is a way of recognizing when the sum overflows the space available for it. With standard decimals, `7+5` forces a "carry" operation: `2, carry the 1` --> `12`.

When the numbers are longer, each digit "cell" can "carry in" -- receive a carry value from the lower-valued cell "to the right", and once the sum in that cell is complete, it can carry out a value to the cell to the left:

```
         1     11    111    111
 456    456    456    456    456
+789   +789   +789   +789   +789
          5     45    245   1245
```

In each step of the sum, a carry might be brought in from the right and sent out to the left.

The same goes for numbers represented in binary, as well. Since the left-most bit is usually the "sign bit", addition can cause a `1` to move into a sign bit position that was previously `0` -- integer overflow, wrapping around into the negatives, on a "carry in" operation. If you add together two negative numbers the sum of the sign bits might force a "carry out" operation -- integer underflow, wrapping around into the positives.